# Making explicit the local structure theorem of étale maps in a very simple case

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Making explicit the local structure theorem of étale maps in a very simple case.

First I recall the following items from Stacks.

**Lemma 10.141.2.** Any étale ring map is standard smooth. More precisely, if $R \to S$ is étale, then there exists a presentation 
$S = R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_n)$
such that the image of $\det(\partial f_j/\partial x_i)$ is invertible in $S$.

Given a prime $Q$ of S we say that $R \to S$ is *étale at $Q$* if there exists a $g \in S$, $g \notin Q$ such that $\varphi:R \to S_g$ is étale.

**Definition 10.141.13.** Let $R$ be a ring. Let $g, f \in R[X]$. Assume that $f$ is monic and the derivative $f'$ is invertible in the localization $R[X]_g/(f)$. In this case the ring map $R \to R[X]_g/(f)$ is said to be *standard étale*.

My remarks.

1) A standard étale map is standard smooth in 2 variables: 
$S\simeq R[x,z]=R[X,Z]/(f(X),Zg(X)-1)$ with Jacobian invertible in $R[x,z]$.

2) What means precisely for a ring map $R \to S$ to be standard étale?

We want an $R$-isomorphism  $\varphi:R[X]_g/(f) \to S=R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

The image  of $\frac{X}{1} \mod f$ by $\varphi$ is some $x=p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, 
$p\in R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, $g(x)$ is invertible in $S$, $f(x)=0$ in $S$. In particular $x$ is integral over $R$ and $f'(x)$ is invertible in $S$.

If $\psi=\varphi^{-1}$, each $\psi(x_i)$ is some $\frac{p_i(X)}{g^m} mod f$.

Finally, $\psi(\varphi(x))=x$ in  $R[X]_g/(f)$, and $\varphi(\psi(x_i))=x_i$ in $S$ for each $i$.

**Proposition 10.141.16.** Let $R \to S$ be a ring map. 
Let $Q\subset S$ be a prime. 
If $R \to S$ is étale at $Q$, then there exists a $h \in S$, 
$h \notin Q$ such that $R \to S_h$ is standard étale.

One can deduce easily the following theorem: 
an equivalent form of 10.141.16, without any prime.

**Theorem.** Let $R \to S$ be an étale ring map.
Then there exists a covering $\operatorname{Spec}(S)= \cup_i D(g_i)$ such that each of the ring maps $R \to S_{g_i}$ is standard étale.

My question is to make explicit this theorem for a very simple example of an étale ring map, given as standard smooth in one variable.

I consider a ring $R$, a degree 3 polynomial $f(X)=aX^3+bX^2+cX+d\in R(X)$. 
I assume that $f'(x)$ is invertible in $S=R[x]=R[X]/(f(X))$.
This means that there exist $u$ and $v$ in $R[X]$ such that $uf+vf'=1$ in $R[X]$. In particular we have $(c,d)=R$.
So the natural map $R\to S$ is an étale ring map (standard smooth in one variable).
In order to make the theorem explicit, we have to find the following objects

- $g_1$, ..., $g_n$ in $S$: I note $S_i=S_{g_i}$,
- $y_1\in S_1$, ..., $y_n\in S_n$,
- $h_i(Y)$ monic in $R[Y]$,
- $k_i(Y)$ in $R[Y]$: I note $R_i=R_{k_i}[Y]/(h_i)$

such that:

- $(g_1,\dots,g_n)=S$,
- $h_i'(Y)/1$ is invertible in $R_i$
- $y_i$ is integral over $R$ in $S_i$, precisely with $h_i(y_i)=0$ in $S_i$, and $k_i(y_i)$ invertible in $S_i$: so we have a map $\varphi_i:R_i\to S_i$ sending the element $\frac{Y}{1} \mod h_i$ of $R_i$ to $y_i$ in $S_i$.
- for each $i$, we have an $x_i\in R_i$ such that $\varphi_i(x_i)=x$ and $g_i(x_i)$ invertible in $R_i$

In this case each  $\varphi_i$ is an isomorphism.

Perhaps a good choice for the $g_i$'s is $g_1=a$, $g_2=ax+b$, $g_3=ax^2+bx+c$.
$y_1$ should be $ax$, but I don't find $y_2$ and $y_3$.